# Android, Background not keeping proportions while writing in TextEditor

Tags: android, background

I've got a problem with a background while writing in `EditText` on my phone.

My background is changing size, and not keeping right proportions.
I would like it to be hidden behind keyboard.

This is my full code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tlo4">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_add_advice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.jagoda.myapplication.AddAdvice">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tytul_add"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style = "@style/tekst"
                android:text=""/>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tytul2_add"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tytul_add"
                style = "@style/tytulDuzy"
                android:text=""/>

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/new_ad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tytul2_add"
                style="@style/tekst2" />

            <Button
                style="@style/przycisk"
                android:text="Dodaj rozwiązanie"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/new_ad"
                android:onClick="to_home"
                android:id="@+id/button"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Before writing in EditText:**

[image: Before writing in EditText]

**While writing in EditText:**

[image: While writing in EditText]

Comment: could you post some images, befor and after writing in `EditText`?

Comment: OK, I added it above.

Comment: in `AndroidManifest` try to add to your activity's body this:`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: ok, I'll add it as an aswear, tick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `AndroidManifest` try to add to your activity's body this: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`